# Player gets stuck on edges between TilemapCollider2D tiles

Tags: unity, collision-detection, tilemap

I'm currently working on a simple 2D Physics-Based Platformer Project. However, I ran into the following issue:
I'm using a Tilemap and a TilemapCollider2D to display the world. When I move the player object, it sometimes gets stuck on the edges between the different squares of the TilemapCollider2D.
Here is a little gif showcasing my problem. Please note that I'm continually pressing A/D to move over the surface. The stopping is the bug I mentioned:
[image]

Here is my player code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{  

Rigidbody2D rb2d;

[Header("Background Variables")]
public float speed = 5.0f;
public float maxSpeed = 10.0f;
public float jumpStrength = 10.0f;
public float friction = 2.5f;

public bool isGrounded = false;
public int walling = 0; // 0 = no wall collision; 1 = left side collision; 2 = right side collision

private void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if(rb2d.velocity.x > maxSpeed)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
    }
    else if(rb2d.velocity.x < -maxSpeed)
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
    }

    if(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0.0f)
    {
        rb2d.AddForce(speed * Vector2.right * Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    else
    {
        rb2d.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(rb2d.velocity, new Vector2(0.0f, rb2d.velocity.y), friction);
    }

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, jumpStrength);
    }
}

// These two methods currently have no effect, but I plan on extending them later
public void SetGrounded(bool isGrounded)
{
    this.isGrounded = isGrounded;
}

public void SetWalling(int walling)
{
    this.walling = walling;
}
}
```

My player uses a Rigidbody2D and BoxCollider2D.
Is there any good way to prevent this from happening or at least a workaround?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you read [previous questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/83585/39518) about [getting stuck](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/68479/39518) at the [borders of box colliders](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146898/39518)? ("tile stuck" makes a good search query for turning up a bunch of them) This is a common physics engine quirk you can learn more about in this [GDC talk by Bennett Foddy](http://gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the)

Comment: @DMGregory
I researched this issue before posting but it seems I simply used the wrong terms for search, sorry.
I didn't know that this is actually a common problem. I think I'll try to see if I can manage to merge the Tilemap Collider Squares into more connected ones.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After trying to write a code that merges the squares effectively (especially for large Tilemaps) both horizontally and vertically I decided to look if there is a better suited collider than the PolygonCollider2D which I've been using.
Then I stumbled across a certain component and now I feel really stupid...

The trick to avoid the problem I mentioned in my question involves absolutely 0 lines of code.

1. For the TilemapCollider2D check the box "Used by Composite".
2. Then add the Component CompositeCollider2D (Found under Physics2D). This will automatically add a Rigidbody2D to your object if it doesn't have one already.
3. Change the "Body Type" of the Rigidbody2D to Kinematic unless you want physical interaction with the tilemap.
4. Profit.

I did some testing and it seems like my problem is solved now. If I should run across another error with this method, I'll update this answer accordingly.

Comment: Now my character falls into the ground a bit every time I land on the platform

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Using `LateUpdate` instead of `FixedUpdate` might be the culprit - try `FixedUpdate`.
- It may also be related to the box collider on your players character - try sphere/capsule colliders instead.

Comment: Using FixedUpate sadly only adds a chance to the jump button not working properly and doesn't fix the situation.
  Edit: I've also already tested the problem with a single stretched out collider (which would be very impractical for a Tilemap), in which case it's gone. This would mean that the entire problem comes from the way a Tilemap divides its collider into squares. 
Also using sphere/capsule colliders causes my player character to jump uncontrollable when moving between the tiles.
All this behaviour would indicate a height difference between the tiles, which does not exist in reality

Comment: I see. I guess I can't be of any help then

Comment: Thank you for trying anyways, though :)

Comment: Using a sphere collider fix this issue for me