# Dealing with ghost vertices of Kinematic bodies in Box2D

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm using LibGDX and Box2D and I want to have multiple falling platforms in a row which will fall sequentially as the player runs on them, like in the picture below. (the shapes are parsed from Tiled)

[image]

When I use simple rectangles I have the problem of ghost vertices.

Chain shapes eliminate them but according to the documentation they are meant for static bodies. I actually gave them a go and indeed when I set a velocity to the Kinematic body they just disappear.

Any idea how I could tackle this? Excuse me if it's something fairly simple, I'm new to box2d.

Comment: Can you describe what the observable symptoms of "ghost vertices" are, that you want to solve?

Comment: When the player runs across the platforms but does not have high enough speed, it gets stopped between the gap. (this happens even if I place the platforms right next to each other with no gap). 

A workaround is to just place each platform slightly lower than the previous one. But this is just a way to bypass the problem, it's not really a solution.

Comment: Have you read [previous questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/83585/39518) about [getting stuck](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/68479/39518) at the [borders of box colliders](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146898/39518)? ("tile stuck" makes a good search query for turning up a bunch of them) This is a common physics engine quirk you can learn more about in this [GDC talk by Bennett Foddy](http://gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the)