# Why cube is getting stuck?

Tags: unity, 3d

The cube sometimes, not always, randomly gets stuck at the edge of new platform. I do not understand why, the platforms are at normal level. And it does not happen all the time. The platform is not plane its a cube, and the next cube is exactly on the same Y position as the previous, not even difference of points.

[image]

Comment: Have you read [previous questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/83585/39518) about [getting stuck](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/68479/39518) at the [borders of box colliders](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146898/39518)? ("tile stuck" makes a good search query for turning up a bunch of them) This is a common physics engine quirk you can learn more about in this [GDC talk by Bennett Foddy](http://gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the).

Comment: How are you moving it?